# Php weird being empty on certain pcs

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have my php running on Centos 6.5 (Final). I have problem where one of my potential customer who is sitting remotely having upon login and redirect the sessions gets empty.He even tried on other machine or browser is the same within that network. Below is the check list I have done.

Every top of the page there is session start
After the redirect statement I have put exit()
Customer have ensure cookies enabled.
What else can I do to overcome this issue? Could it be server side or client side issue ?

Below is snippet of codes..

```
session_start(); 
//echo "USER ID is : ".$_SESSION['userID'];
//echo "USER nameis : ".$_SESSION['userName'];

if($_SESSION['userID']=="" || $_SESSION['userName']=="")
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: paste your code please

Comment: If it does it on all machines and/or browsers but for that user only, it's definitely an application issue, not a client nor server issue.

Comment: Not it does not on all machines just this particular few machines

Comment: @psal I have pasted the codes for u

Comment: @user2711681 Does the clients browser allow cookies? These will be needed to connect to the same session every time.

Comment: "Customer have ensure cookies enabled" = I've heard that before :) I always get them to fill in this form which will give me a better understanding of their current setup. Then you can try and replicate it at your end: http://supportdetails.com/ Also try on your mobile and see if the same thing happens there. It sounds like your session identifier/id/namespace could be changing.

Comment: Yes the customer have enabled cookies. Yes I have tried from my phone and also their phone it works just that the pc is not working and also some other pc on their lan too

Comment: How to determine that my session id are changing ?

Comment: You could easily do some file log debugging for this particular user by checking for their ID and seeing if sets cookies (`if(someuser){ setcookie('test', 1, time()+3600); if(count($_COOKIE) < 1){ error_log(user doesn't have cookies enabled); }}`

Comment: Where do you want me to put this codes and what is the if(someuser) is ? Another thing I read is it true that when calling header not to put the http:// I am trying this too